# I am trying to build using docker desktop on Mac

Tags: macos, docker

But it seems to get the following error. I have cloned the package and have access rights to it.

`failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed`

**EDIT**

This error seems to be due to docker on M1 chip and not because of any repo access. The error is same when I run getting-started guide. I can't build anything using Docker for Desktop on Mac.

**EDIT 2**

I tried building with sudo and it worked fine. The error seems to be with Repository builds as they don't use sudo and I have been updating DOCKER_BUILD_SUDO=sudo but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the access to the repository, but to the image registry:

```
pull access denied ... insufficient_scope
```

If you have the credentials, prior to building issue a [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) command. If not, you'll need to either ask for them the maintainer or you're out of luck unless you find an alternative (public) image and replace it in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I just got to know that it is not an issue of repo access. but  this problem persists for docker on M1 chip. I was trying to build the getting-started guide and got the same error.   ```failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = open /Users/dnabanita7/.docker/.token_seed: permission denied```

Comment: @chad7 Why would such a high-level error/issue be caused by the M1 chip and therefore low-level hardware/architecture? If that were the case, you'd get far worse errors by this point and not only by Docker.

Comment: I tried building with `sudo` and it worked fine. The error seems to be with Repository builds as they don't use `sudo` and I have been updating `DOCKER_BUILD_SUDO=sudo` but the issue persists.